# Installing Copernic Desktop fails with error

Tags: windows-10, installation

I'm attempting to install Copernic Desktop Search on Windows 10. I get a message:

> "An error occurred during installation of assembly
> 'Microsoft.VT90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002"

The installer then reports that it has ended prematurely.

Copernic Support informed me that the computer's NET framework needed repairing, but running Microsoft's NET Repair Tool has had no effect.

Can anyone suggest a course of actio that might resolve this problem?

Comment: Both the 32-bit and 64-but versions of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package are installed on your system?  What version of .NET did the publisher of the application say is required exactly?  What version of Windows 10 are you using?  .NET on Windows 10 cannot actually be repaired

Comment: I can almost guarantee (99%) the problem is that the correct Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is NOT installed.  Only recent versions of the Redistributable are binary compatible.  The one the author needs is not, which means, they must install that specific version of the VC++ Redistributable.